# how to build a query with if statements

Tags: sql

I want to get data from database using the users input

```
    int fnameNum = 0;
        int lnameNum = 0;
        int emailNum = 0;

        if (firstName != null) {
            sb.append(" E.FIRST_NAME = ? ");
            fnameNum = 1;
            if (email == null) {
                sb.append(" AND ");
                sb.append(" E.LAST_NAME LIKE ? ");
                lnameNum = 2;
            } else if (lastName == null) {
                sb.append(" AND ");
                sb.append(" E.EMAIL = ? ");
                emailNum = 2;
            } else {
                sb.append(" AND ");
                sb.append(" E.LAST_NAME LIKE ? ");
                lnameNum = 2;
                sb.append(" AND ");
                sb.append(" E.EMAIL = ? ");
                emailNum = 3;
            }
        }

        String sqlString = sb.toString();
        preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);

        if (fnameNum > 0) {
            preStatement.setString(fnameNum, firstName);
        }
        if (lnameNum > 0) {
            preStatement.setString(lnameNum, lastName + "%");
        }
        if (emailNum > 0) {
            preStatement.setString(emailNum, email);
        }

        ResultSet rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

There's 3 textbox in html. I want to get data from database according to the inputs of the user even if the the other textbox is blank or all the textbox are filled with data.

Comment: you need to write a sql function or store procedure

Comment: `case when` maybe solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the worst possible idea to create SQL statement with string concatenation. You will have plenty of penalties/concerns with this method. Some of them are:

- Open to SQL Injection
- DBMS cannot optimize query (because it is dynamically changing)
- Not readable (Developer friendly)

The best possible option to do this is to use named parameters (if it is supported by your DBMS system). See  an example  below:

```
SELECT * from TBL
WHERE (:NAME is null or NAME = :NAME) AND
      (:SURNAME is NULL or SURNAME = :SURNAME)
```

Comment: its throwing a exception if i leave a one or more textbox as blank

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using oracle sql

Comment: It wont be problem with oracle. You may need to explicitly set to null. blank may be just blank string `''`

Comment: @YohanDeRamos . . . Although the reasons given in this answer are true, the answer itself is not correct.  Constructing the SQL only for the columns that have values can be a very important way to improve performance, because it can allow indexes to be used on the final query that would not (necessarily) be used with complex combinations of `AND`/`OR`.  Oracle actually implements something called a skip-scan, so it handles `OR` better than other databases, but you may want to construct the query clause by clause for performance reasons.